# instance variable shared by objects?

Tags: objective-c

I declared an instance variable (**not** static), just a regular variable in the @implementation section.  When I accessed that variable from several objects it appeared that all the objects were sharing the same variable, as if I had declared it static!

I then changed the instance variable to a (strong) property (defined in the .m file to make it private) and it started working as expected, with each object getting their own separate version of the property.

What was going on with that weird "sharing" behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't declare an instance variable.  You defined a global variable.  You did this:

```
@implementation MyObject

int myVariable;
```

but you should have done this:

```
@implementation MyObject {
    int myVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you define a regular var in the @implementation, you define a global variable. For example, in a.m, you define:

```
@implementation classA

int tryMe = 99;
```

Then in b.m, you use also use tryMe:

```
@implementation classB

-(void) func {
    extern int tryMe;
    NSLog(@"%i", tryMe); // This will print 99.
}
```

But if you use "static" in a.m, then you will get build error, you will be told that "tryMe" could not be found. Because "static" make the variable local to the file which defines the var.

While, if you define a var as property, then the var is a member of the class, so each instance of the class has its own copy of the var.